# The number of unknown variables in the growth path model

Tags: variance, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable

[image]

It's a path model of growth over time with variance-covariance matrix.

So, there are 7*8/2= 28 known variances and covariances.

But the textbook says that are 27 unknowns (7*x + 7*u + 6*w + 6*z + the variance of A1).

I don't understand why the variance of A1 must be solved.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variance of A1 is estimated from the data, it is not constrained in the model.  (Although be warned that some SEM programs will *not* treat this as a parameter to be estimated, because it is exogenous.

One way to think about it. You could add a parameter z1 to A1. A1 has no predictors, so the R^2 would be zero. z1 would be estimated, and its variance would be equal to the variance of A1. These two models would be the same.

Comment: thanks a lot much appreciated!